# Error when i tried ng add @ngrx/store@latest --minimal false

Tags: angular, ngrx

When i tried  useng add @ngrx/store@latest --minimal false in my angular poject i see next error

```
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"minimal":"false"}
Errors:

  Data path "/minimal" must be boolean.
```

Comment: I'm just shooting in the dark, but can you check if `ng add @ngrx/store@latest --minimal=false` works?

Answer (score 3):

Angular-CLI uses --option / --no-option for boolean flags (https://angular.io/cli#boolean-options).

In this case:

```
ng add @ngrx/store@latest --no-minimal
```